# Loop to find the count the repeat of data

Tags: python, dataframe

my data set is composed of time and data. I want to count the data until there is gap in time between the two data recorded. I tried doing this way but its not working, and is there a better way to do in dataframe

```
def convertToEvents(entries, gap):
    results = []
    i = 0
    prevTime = 0
    while i < len(entries):
        time = entries[i][0]
        current = entries[i][1]
        if time > prevTime + gap:
            results.append((time, current,1))
        elif current > entries[i-1][1]:
            results[-1] = (results[-1][0], current, time-results[-1][0])
        else:
            results[-1] = (results[-1][0], results[-1][1], time-results[-1][0])
        prevTime = entries[i][0]
        i+=1
    return results
```

Comment: Yes there is a better way to do this, but we'll need more details about your dataframe, preferably a sample of both it and your expected output, before we can help.

Comment: Point: My actual data is larger than the given sample. Here is the sample of my data set                                                                                           '''Time 1653177483  1653177484  1653177485  1653177486'''                                        '''current 10   45   52   61  23   22'''